# SpeechClient.PollUntilComplete hanging

Tags: c#, google-cloud-speech

Using the code below, the PollUntilComplete() method never returns

```
string uri = $"gs://{bucket}/{selectedFile}";
RecognitionConfig config = new RecognitionConfig()
{
   Encoding = RecognitionConfig.Types.AudioEncoding.Linear16,
   SampleRateHertz = int.Parse(sampleRateComboBox.Text),
   LanguageCode = "en",
   Model = "default"
   };
RecognitionAudio audio = RecognitionAudio.FromStorageUri(uri);
if (audio.Content != null)
{
   var longOperation = speech.LongRunningRecognize(config, audio);
   toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Processing: " + selectedFile;
   Console.WriteLine("Transcript: ");
   longOperation = longOperation.PollUntilCompleted(null, null, 
     new Action<LongRunningRecognizeMetadata>((LongRunningRecognizeMetadata obj) =>
     {
        Console.WriteLine($"Last Update Time: {obj.LastUpdateTime.ToDateTime()
           .ToString()}, Percent Complete: {obj.ProgressPercent}");
     }));
   }
```

If I start the process using the gcloud CLI it works. So I know the source file and the account credentials are valid.
Any suggestions about what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the image below, my callback took a few seconds. But my audio file is about 20 seconds long. It may be that your file is longer.

[google speech to text with poll until completed callback](https://i.stack.imgur.com/csvkO.png)

Comment: Hi, Can you edit the answer with that code and explain what you have done to solve the problem? This will help others to understand the solution and get a broader understanding of the solution.